# sanity upgrade ERROR: Couldn't find package "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@^7.10.4" required by "@sanity/core@^2.18.0"

Tags: npm, babeljs, sanity

I'm using fedora Linux when I used `sanity upgrade` command in my studio folder i had this error :

```
✖ Resolving dependencies
✖ Couldn't find package "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@^7.10.4" required by "@sanity/core@^2.18.0" on the "npm" registry.
✖ Resolving dependencies

Error: Command failed :(
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:3260:2554
    at async Object.e.default [as action] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:4828:2053)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dependency hasn't changed in 2.18.0 so hopefully deleting your node_modules (`rm -rf node_modules`) and installing again will get things working.